# Finding the highest normal form a given relation

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I am doing some prep for my DB final and am stack with this question. I am a bit lost with this question and would appreciate if you could tell me if I am moving in the right direction

This is the question:

> Takes(Id, Name, Course)
>
> Assume that Id is a candidate key, but that
> there are no other functional dependencies. What is the highest normal
> form that this relation satisfies? (Hint, think about the normal form
> conditions.)

What confuses me is the ID: since it is a candidate key, it can be used to identify either Name or Course, so one of them is not necessary. In that case the relation wont satisfy even the 1NF, correct?

Thanks

Comment: There is insufficient justification for it *not* meeting [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) - 1NF basically says "don't store collections in columns" (neither Name nor Course violate this) and "each tuple must be a candidate key" (which is ensured because Id is a candidate key).

Comment: If 1NF is ok, then it looks like it meets 2NF too, because there is no data that applies to multiple rows, correct?